# Collision issue in cloth simulation

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, collision

I'm just starting to learn Blender and while going through a tutorial I stumbled upon a problem that I can't solve. During the cloth simulation, the plane does not collide with the objects (couch cushions). Might someone have an idea as to why?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots the file is too large unfortunately, its over 300 mb

Comment: only keep the useful objects and share on another platform, for example workupload.com

Comment: https://workupload.com/archive/hzE5m2SgAX
here it is, although I think having it fixed. I needed to fix the normals, to highten the subd level and tinker with selfcollision and collision settings

Comment: oh ok then maybe write your own answer

Answer (score 0):

I needed to fix the normals, to highten the subd level and tinker with selfcollision and collision settings